# Datepicker not loading in IE - MVC 4, Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, razor, datepicker

Need your help on below.

I've below code in my view for datepicker which works perfectly in chrome but in IE nothing is loaded.

```
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker();
        $("#EndDate").datepicker();
    });
 </script>

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { style = "width:200px;height:34px;", type = "date" })
```

Below are the references added in _layout.cshtml

```
<script src="~/obj/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/obj/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try removing `type = "date"`. If its not generating a datepicker then it means you scripts are not loading (`type = "date"` generates the browsers datepicker, not the jquery datepicker and its only supported in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support "data" attribute. 
Input type DATE is an HTML5 feature which is not supported by all browsers. In case you want to use HTML5 feature not supported by your browser (which usually will be IE) then use two things:

Feature Detection
Polyfills
Feature Detection is the ability to determine if an HTML5 feature is supported or not by our browser. A good library for that is Modernizr. What you can do with modernizr is detect if any feature that you need is not supported and if not then you can conditionally load some javascript libraries that will implement that feature. Those libraries are called Polyfills.

So for example if you want to use the tag in IE 10 you could use the jqueryui.com controls to provide a date picker.

```
Modernizr.load({
test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
nope: "js/jquery-ui.custom.js",
callback: function() {
  $("input[type=date]").datepicker();
}
```

});

Modernizr tests is the feature is supported, optionally you can use the nope to indicate if there is a library that you wan t to load ONLY if the feature is not supported, and callback is code that will be called after the test and after loading the library.